# Is it possible to get typename by index in template?

Tags: c++, c++11

how do something like this? where I could get the specific typename in an argument list?

```
template <class... T>
struct TableLookUp::SmartMap
{
private:
    table<T[0]> OurMap;
    x_axis<T[1]> Our_x_axis;
    y_axis<T[2]> Our_y_axis;
}
```

Comment: Don't use variadic template arguments and use three different template parameters.

Comment: Maybe, with [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and [std::tuple_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element)...

Comment: @Holt: It might be that the extra elements are intentionally ignored. Still, you'd then write `template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename... ignored>`

Comment: @MSalters Sure, but I can't really figure a valid reason to do something like the given example. Wanting to access a type at a specific (hard-coded) index like that looks like bad design to me.

Comment: @Holt:  A valid reason would be template metaprogramming: you need to provide a template as an argument to another template, and that other template will instantiate your template with a variable-length argument list.

Comment: `using Types = std::tuple<T...>;` and then `std::tuple_element_t<0, Types>` where you want `T[0]`. But I agree it's rather pointless - it makes more sense to give the first three template parameters explicit names to begin with.